# style trigger on datagrid element name

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to set my styles inside the window.resources tag
I need to set the maxlength property on a DatagridTextColumn but i cannot find a working solution.

The windows resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CellEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{??? ElementName=RefFourn ???}">
                <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="19"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RefFourn" Header="Ref Fourn" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=RefFourn, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
</Datagrid.Columns
</Datagrid>
```

Comment: Conditions are not clear.
When you want to define the max length?

Comment: when the form load

Comment: So you don't need a Trigger.
You just need to define a setter in the CellEditStyle.

Comment: If i do that, i'll have to remove the EditingElementStyle property, so to re-write the content of the resource style tag inside each of my columns. I consider this as duplicate code and hard to read/maintain. So i don't want to set my styles inside each column but in window.resources styles.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: Usually we create both styles for Edit Cell and for Readonly.
You can create TextBlock style for your Readonly cell with Width limitation and text trimming.

Comment: This : <DataGridTextColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}">
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>

</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
is not permitted

Comment: So you need it only for special value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123137/discussion-between-ebelair-and-mr-b).

Answer (score -2):

Change your style as below:

```
  <Style x:Key="CellEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="19"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>               
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```